# django admin search by foreign key in add form

Tags: django

In the form to add new objects in Django admin, sometimes there are linked foreign keys that are selectable in a dropdown. Is there a way to include a searchbox for the foreign keys within the form?

For example, let's say I have a Book model with a foreign key to Author object. Instead of scrolling through all the author ids when I create a new Book object, can I search for Author "James" specifically?

Comment: If you are using default add form, then you can use either `raw_id_fields` or `autocomplete_fields`

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for! Sorry but I will be accepting Boketto's answer since he/she raised it as an answer first.

Comment: no problem, always glad to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use autocomplete fields in your custom admin.

[Django Documentation - Autocomplete Fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields)